# SQL select to get a string between two Special Characters

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have data like ABC_DEF_123,DEF_GHI_345,GHI_JKL_678
I need to select 123,345,678 (i.e) Between "," and "*"
How to select between "," and last "*"
Data is not a static one.
Help me out...
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try below code ,try to wrap below code in function

```
DECLARE @string NVARCHAR(MAX)='ABC_DEF_123,DEF_GHI_345,GHI_JKL_678'
DECLARE @delimiter CHAR(1)=','
DECLARE @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) )
BEGIN 
DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
    IF @end = 0  
        SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

    INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
    VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
    SET @start = @end + 1 
    SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

END 
--
DECLARE @values NVARCHAR(max)=''
SELECT @values=RIGHT(splitdata,3)+','+@values FROM @output ORDER BY splitdata DESC

SELECT  (SUBSTRING(@values,0,LEN(@values))) 
END
```

Comment: output for above query is : 678,345,123. but the reqd output is 123,345,678.  for this Modify last two lines as :                                  SELECT @values=@values+','+RIGHT(splitdata,3) FROM @output SELECT  (SUBSTRING(@values,2,LEN(@values)+1))

Comment: Instead of that you can use `REVERSE` function. I have updated Ans.

Comment: Please check your query. Now output is 321,543,876

Answer (score 0):

Try the below script which may help you

select right('ABC_DEF_123',3)  as DataValue

select substring('ABC_DEF_123',patindex('%[0-9]%','ABC_DEF_123'),len('ABC_DEF_123'))